# How to display products which have same attribute value as related products in Product view page?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-relations, products-view

I have a requirement where, in product details (view) page, I need to display related products which are having the same color as of the product being viewed.

For example, I'm on a page which shows a "Red" Shoe, I should have a Red T-shirt, Red-Refrigerator, Red anything else to be displayed as related products (maximum 5 products).

I know this can be done easily in Enterprise edition, but how to do this in Community edition?

Any help please?

**note:**

> All products are simple products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new block (and maybe a new template). Here is how you get the product collection for your needs:

```
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($currentProduct){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add some attribtues to select
        ->addMinimalPrice() //add prices to select
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq'=>$currentProduct->getColor());//filter products with the same color
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //only active products
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);//only visible products
    $collection->setPage(1,5);//limit to 5 products
}
else{
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
}
```

Now in `$collection` you should have the products you need. You can use that in your custom template.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing in Magento CE 1.9.1.0 . Basically I want to edit the related products block to show all products that have the same value for a specific attribute. Basically I have an attribute called family and when you view product abc which belongs to the attribute family 'Pepsi' I want to display all other products that have a value for the family attribute of 'pepsi'

So I am altering the file 
app/design/frontend/MY_THEME/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml

The first thing I do in this file is get the value of the family attribute by doing the below

```
            //get the name of the family that the product being viewed is a part of
             $itemcollectionname = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('family');
```

I then tried using the code in the above post like so

```
             $rcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add some attribtues to select
             ->addAttributeToFilter('family', array('eq'=>$itemcollectionname);//filter products with the same family
             Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($rcollection); //only active products
             Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($rcollection);//only visible products
            $rcollection->setPage(1,5);//limit to 5 products
            echo "$rcollection<br />";
```