# Automatic assign Up-Sell products with same attribute data

Tags: product, up-sells

If a store have a lot of products, it's impossible to assign up-sell products for each items

e.g. If A123 product have 'Blue' as 'Color' attribute,

I want to show all items which have 'Blue' as 'Color' attribute as A123's up-sell items

automatically on front-end (so I don't have to assign up-sell for every items)

Any solution or extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds you need to create a custom product collection based on attribute filters with a limit of how many products you want.  Once you have that, you'll need to render that in a block to be displayed on the product page.

If you have any specific questions about that, please edit your post. Also, please [see the answer to a similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/how-to-display-products-which-have-same-attribute-value-as-related-products-in-p).